# Is there a way to display a list of Many2many in a formated string in odoo?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, odoo-15

I work with odoo 15 in python 3.10, and I want to set a field automaticaly based on a Many2many field.
In my case, the field set is the name of the participants to an activity, my method looks like this:

```
    def name_get(self):
        return [
            (record.id, "%s | %s - %s" % (record.users_ids.name, record.period_start, record.period_end))
            for record in self
        ]
```

---

It doesn't work because the field `users_ids` is many2many and I can't seem to find anything about this online.
An idea I had was to make a list of the names of the participants based on the `users_ids` field, but I don't know how to finalize it.

For the moment I didn't try anything, expect the function that I wrote earlier on.

What should I do ?

Comment: Do you need to show all user names concatenated with the record period start/end?

Comment: Yes, something like:
user1 - user2 - user3 - user4 - ... - userN - period_start - period_end

Comment: Try [computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#computed-fields)